# back button with react-navigation on specific screen dynamically

Tags: react-navigation, back-button

on react-navigation i am trying to navigate to a specific screen which depends on some condition! 
Below it is pointing to 'App' page right now 
but sometimes i need it to go to 'Main' page

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: 'Tools',
      headerLeft: (
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('App')}
          title="Back"
        />
      ),
    };
  };
```

when i use state or function 
for example

...
...

onPress={() => navigation.navigate(this.someFunction())}

...
...

there is an error undefined is not an object

so how do I point dynamically the desirable page to navigate to?

Answer (score 0):

if came from any screen , want to go back dynamic without defining the screen name in navigation . Use this method :

onPress={()=>navigation.goBack()}

navigation.goBack() method will take you directly on the screen where it came from .